# Full-text search against string (databaseless)

Tags: full-text-search, document

Is there a way to perform a search in a document which I don't want to be stored anywhere? I've got some experience with Sphinx search and ElasticSearch and it seems they both operate on a database of some kind. I want to search a word in a single piece of text, in a string variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `nltk` and `pymorphy` just tokenizing my text and comparing stems/normalized morphological forms from pymorphy with search items. No need for any heavy full-text search weaponry.